# Why is the Span that's nested in a Label preventing other nested items' ability to click to select checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, ember.js, label

The template is pretty simple, a checkbox component and string of text nested inside a label element:

```
<label class="statusList-label">
  {{list-checkbox
    value=object.id
    sourceList=item.objectIds
    class=""}}
  {{object.name}}
</label>
```

The checkbox template nested inside looks like this:

```
<span>
  <input type="checkbox" class="u-display-none">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg {{if checked 'fa-check-square' 'fa-square-
  o'}}
  fa-checkbox {{if disabled 'disabled'}}" unselectable="on">
  </i>
</span>
```

Now, the expected behaviour is that clicking on anything nested inside the `<label>` tag should toggle the `<input>` inside. However, clicking on the `object.name` that gets outputted to the DOM does not work - only clicking on items inside the `<span>` works. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the HTML output:

```
<div class="item">
  <label class="itemLabel">
    <span unselectable="on" id="ember1173" class="cell cell--checkbox ember-view">
      <input type="checkbox" class="u-display-none">
      <i unselectable="on" class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-square fa-checkbox "></i>
      <!---->
    </span>
    Some Text Here
  </label>
</div>
```

EDIT 2: Figured it out.. there was preventDefault on the parent component to handle click events for some other behaviour. Just had to remove that..

Comment: Is it possible to show the HTML that is generated from your code? A [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Just added the HTML output.

Comment: Write an answer yourself and select it as the accepted one if you have figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.. there was `preventDefault()` on the parent component to handle click events for some other behaviour. Just had to remove that..